# Clarifying which segement of a curve overlap is in the foreground/background

Tags: plotting, visualization, parametric-functions, style

I plotted the left curve using regular `ParametricPlot3D`. In parts where the curve overlaps itself, it is unclear which segment is in the foreground and which in the background. At least for more complicated curves, this can make it tricky to fully graps the spacial embedding.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the effect in the right image (I did it with photoshop)? Maybe by creating some white "halo" around the curve (in some clever way)?

---

**Minimal working code example**

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.13 t}, {t, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.013]},
    Axes -> None,
    Boxed -> False
]
```

Comment: @Rahul Thank you, this helped perfectly. Especially [your answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48192/53397).

Comment: @Rahul This might be a seperate question or maybe fit better below your answer in the other question, but is there a short answer to "how can I make the line in my `ParametricPlot3D` into a tube, so that I can apply this idea", and yes I want to use `ParametricPlot3D` and not `Graphics3D`.

Comment: Yes, this should probably be a separate question. And in fact, it already is, many times. Search for "ParametricPlot3D Tube" on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this question is a duplicate and the problem was solved by Rahul's great answer [over here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48192/53397), I still want to provide the full code of my solution. This isvolves how I transferred the solution to work with `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
f[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.2 t};
Show[
  (* the actual black curve *)
  ParametricPlot3D[
    f[t], {t, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.013]}
  ],

  (* the tube around the curve which hides the background curve at overlaps *)
  ParametricPlot3D[
    f[t], {t, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {CapForm@None, FaceForm[None, Glow[White]]},
    Lighting -> None
  ] /. Line[L_] -> Tube[L, 0.05],

  Axes -> None,
  BoxStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.5]},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, Automatic}
]
```

[image]